# Error during installation of CalyxOS: Sending sparse 'system_a' 2/4 - (Error reading sparse file)

Tags: android, smartphone

I tried to install CalyxOS on my Pixel 4a(5G). The installation went well until an error occurs (see log). I wasn't able to start anything. I just came to the fastboot menu - nothing more worked. So I went through a complete re-installation by using the [Google Factory Flash][1], which worked very well. After that, I was able to Start Google Android again like it was brand new out of the factory.

So I downloaded the image again and tried to install CalyxOS the second time, **but unfortunately, the process stopped again at the exact same step**. What should I do? I now have to flash again, but then? Any Ideas?

```
Android Factory Image Flasher version 1.0.3
Extracting bramble-factory-2.7.0.zip
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r30.0.4-windows.zip
Downloading... 8.4 MB downloaded
Verifying platform-tools_r30.0.4-windows.zip
Extracting platform-tools_r30.0.4-windows.zip
1. Connect to a wifi network and ensure that no SIM cards are installed
2. Enable Developer Options on device (Settings -> About Phone -> tap "Build number" 7 times)
3. Enable USB debugging on device (Settings -> System -> Advanced -> Developer Options) and allow the computer to debug (hit "OK" on the popup when USB is connected)
4. Enable OEM Unlocking (in the same Developer Options menu)

Press ENTER to continue

Detected bramble 14221JECB06677

Devices to be flashed:
bramble 14221JECB06677

Press ENTER to continue
Unlocking bramble 14221JECB06677 bootloader...
5. Please use the volume and power keys on the device to unlock the bootloader
Flashing bramble 14221JECB06677 bootloader...
Sending 'bootloader_a' (8754 KB)                   OKAY [  0.338s]
Writing 'bootloader_a'                             (bootloader) Flashing Pack version b5-0.3-7241846
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 0
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 1
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 2
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 4
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 5
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_config_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition aop_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition tz_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition hyp_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition abl_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition keymaster_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition devcfg_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition qupfw_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition uefisecapp_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition featenabler_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition logfs
OKAY [  0.260s]
Finished. Total time: 0.863s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.048s]
Finished. Total time: 0.052s
< waiting for any device >
Sending 'radio_a' (149780 KB)                      OKAY [  3.948s]
Writing 'radio_a'                                  (bootloader) Flashing Pack version SSD:g7250-00132-210419-B-7294132
(bootloader) Flashing partition modem_a
OKAY [  0.809s]
Finished. Total time: 5.023s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.048s]
Finished. Total time: 0.052s
< waiting for any device >
Erasing 'avb_custom_key'                           OKAY [  0.215s]
Finished. Total time: 0.339s
Sending 'avb_custom_key' (0 KB)                    OKAY [  0.138s]
Writing 'avb_custom_key'                           OKAY [  0.221s]
Finished. Total time: 0.556s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.047s]
Finished. Total time: 0.051s
< waiting for any device >
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: b5-0.3-7241846
Baseband Version.....: g7250-00132-210419-B-7294132
Serial Number........: 14221JECB06677
--------------------------------------------
extracting android-info.txt (0 MB) to RAM...
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.067s]
Checking 'version-bootloader'                      OKAY [  0.067s]
Checking 'version-baseband'                        OKAY [  0.066s]
Setting current slot to 'a'                        OKAY [  0.082s]
extracting boot.img (96 MB) to disk... took 0.268s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
Sending 'boot_a' (98304 KB)                        OKAY [  2.688s]
Writing 'boot_a'                                   OKAY [  0.482s]
extracting dtbo.img (16 MB) to disk... took 0.040s
archive does not contain 'dtbo.sig'
Sending 'dtbo_a' (16384 KB)                        OKAY [  0.478s]
Writing 'dtbo_a'                                   OKAY [  0.143s]
archive does not contain 'dt.img'
archive does not contain 'recovery.img'
extracting vbmeta.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.000s
archive does not contain 'vbmeta.sig'
Sending 'vbmeta_a' (8 KB)                          OKAY [  0.138s]
Writing 'vbmeta_a'                                 OKAY [  0.075s]
extracting vbmeta_system.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.001s
archive does not contain 'vbmeta_system.sig'
Sending 'vbmeta_system_a' (4 KB)                   OKAY [  0.138s]
Writing 'vbmeta_system_a'                          OKAY [  0.075s]
extracting vendor_boot.img (96 MB) to disk... took 0.196s
archive does not contain 'vendor_boot.sig'
Sending 'vendor_boot_a' (98304 KB)                 OKAY [  2.419s]
Writing 'vendor_boot_a'                            OKAY [  0.469s]
extracting super_empty.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.000s
Rebooting into fastboot                            OKAY [  0.065s]
< waiting for any device >
Sending 'super' (4 KB)                             OKAY [  0.002s]
Updating super partition                           OKAY [  0.008s]
Resizing 'product_a'                               OKAY [  0.004s]
Resizing 'system_a'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Resizing 'system_ext_a'                            OKAY [  0.005s]
Resizing 'system_b'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Resizing 'vendor_a'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Resizing 'vendor_b'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
archive does not contain 'boot_other.img'
archive does not contain 'odm.img'
extracting product.img (994 MB) to disk... took 3.752s
archive does not contain 'product.sig'
Resizing 'product_a'                               OKAY [  0.005s]
Sending sparse 'product_a' 1/4 (262140 KB)         OKAY [  6.571s]
Writing 'product_a'                                OKAY [  2.533s]
Sending sparse 'product_a' 2/4 (262140 KB)         OKAY [  6.435s]
Writing 'product_a'                                OKAY [  1.567s]
Sending sparse 'product_a' 3/4 (262140 KB)         OKAY [  6.438s]
Writing 'product_a'                                OKAY [  1.553s]
Sending sparse 'product_a' 4/4 (231696 KB)         OKAY [  5.773s]
Writing 'product_a'                                OKAY [  1.381s]
extracting system.img (801 MB) to disk... took 3.667s
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
Resizing 'system_a'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Sending sparse 'system_a' 1/4 (262140 KB)          OKAY [  6.492s]
Writing 'system_a'                                 OKAY [  2.535s]
Sending sparse 'system_a' 2/4 (262140 KB)          FAILED (Error reading sparse file)
fastboot: error: Command failed
Rebooting into bootloader
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having `FAILED (Error reading sparse file)` issue when I was connecting the USB cable to the dock of my laptop.

Instead connecting the USB Type-A end directly to my laptop port helped me fix this problem. Be mindful of USB 3.0, USB Type C and USB 2.0 ports (try with all) and run your commands in command prompt in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**  First, I had to change the USB Cable. I got an error during installation all the time. The cabel USB-C<>USB-A from my old HTC was the solution....very strange but just after using it, my Google 4a(5G) was detected correctly from my PC.

I also installed ADB manually before lunching the device flasher.

```
sudo apt-get install adb
```

The error also pooped up, because I had to re-approve on the device, that USB-Debugging is allowed (simply de-activating for giving the approval to my PC). I checked it with:

```
adb devices
```

After that my device was detected correctly.

Then I ran the flasher and everything went fine.